# Defining functions for connected sets

Tags: differential-geometry, convex-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ an open, bounded and connected set with a $C^2$ boundary and a function $\rho \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that
$$ \Omega = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \rho(x) < 0 \},\quad \partial \Omega = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \rho(x) = 0 \},\quad |\nabla \rho(x)|=1\ \ \text{on}\ \partial \Omega.$$
My question is the following : is there $\epsilon > 0$ small enough such that the sets
$$  \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \rho(x) <  \epsilon \},\quad \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \rho(x) < -\epsilon \}$$
are still connected ?

My intuition tells me that it is true because if a new connected component appeared for any $\epsilon$, it would mean that there exists a critical point $x_0$ on the boundary for which $\nabla \rho(x_0) = 0$. However, I have troubles to prove this rigoureously. 
What do you think ?

Comment: There are obvious guesses as to what "smooth" means, but could you please add your definition to the question? Also, could you say something about where the question comes from (particularly, what do you know about the boundary of a "smooth open, bounded, connected set"?), and do you have any thoughts of your own?

Comment: Think about the n=1 case. You essentially have a smooth graph which has a single "dip" under the x axis. This chunk of the x axis is omega. What happens with epsilon when it is big, small, limiting on 0 or infinity?

Comment: Hint: Can you think of a _positive_ one-variable function $\rho$ (so that $\Omega = \emptyset$) with the property that the sub-level set $\{x : \rho(x) < \varepsilon\}$ is disconnected for every $\varepsilon > 0$, or prove such a function does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(t) = e^{-t^{2}(1 + \cos \pi t)}$ is smooth, even, and satisfies
$$
e^{-2t^{2}} \leq f(t) \leq 1\quad\text{for all real $t$,}
$$
with the lower equality achieved at every even integer and the upper achieved at every odd integer.

[image: A smooth, positive function with infinitely many low valleys]

If $\|x\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm on $\mathbf{R}^{n}$, then
$$
\rho(x) = f\bigl(\|x\|\bigr)
$$
is smooth and positive, so the sub-level set $\Omega = \{t : \rho(t) < 0\}$ is empty, but for every $\epsilon > 0$, the sublevel set $\Omega_{\epsilon} = \{t : \rho(t) < \epsilon\}$ has infinitely many connected components.

(It's straightforward to modify this example so that $\Omega$ is non-empty; for example, take
$$
f(t) = \frac{t^{2} - c^{2}}{t^{2} + 1}e^{-t^{2}(1 + \cos \pi t)},
$$
with $c$ chosen so that $|f'(c)| = 1$.)

---

That said, it looks possible to prevent this type of counterexample by assuming $\rho$ has a positive lower bound outside some compact set $K$. Here's a sketch.

Since the zero set of $\rho$ is $\partial\Omega$ and $|\nabla\rho| = 1$ on $\partial\Omega$, $0$ is not a critical value of $\rho$. If $\rho$ has a positive lower bound outside $K$, there is an $\eta > 0$ such that $\rho$ has no critical values in $(-\eta, \eta)$. (Otherwise, there is a sequence of critical points $(x_{k})$ in $K$ such that $\rho(x_{k}) \to 0$; by Bolzano-Weierstrass, we may assume $(x_{k})$ converges to a point $x$ of $K$. Continuity of $\rho$ implies $\rho(x) = 0$, while continuity of $\nabla\rho$ implies $x$ is a critical point, contrary to the hypotheses in the question.)

The claim is now that if $|\epsilon| < \eta/2$, then the sublevel set $\Omega_{\epsilon}$ has the same homotopy type as $\Omega$. (In particular, if $\Omega$ is connected, then $\Omega_{\epsilon}$ is connected.) For this, borrow from Morse theory the idea of looking at the flow of $-\nabla\rho/|\nabla\rho|^{2}$ (in the complement of the critical set of $\rho$, which contains the neighborhood
$$
\Omega_{\eta}\setminus\overline{\Omega}_{-\eta}
  = \{x : |\rho(x)| < \eta\}
$$
of $\partial\Omega$). If $|t| < \eta/2$, then $|\epsilon - t| < \eta$, and the time-$t$ flow maps the level set of $\rho$ at height $\epsilon$ to the level set of height $\epsilon - t$, and continuously retracts $\Omega_{\epsilon}$ to $\Omega_{\epsilon-t}$. (Milnor's *Morse Theory* contains more details, if memory serves.)